# Parameters inside the function

Tags: c

I have a work to do in which I have to keep a loop inside the function expecting the following parameters:
-"i" to insert
-"s" to search
-"q" to quit

How do I keep this loop? I've looked up some options and it seems to be possible using a while or a switch, but I am not sure which is the best way to read those chars (with a fscanf perhaps?). I am also not sure how to read the things after the parameter "i" as the input would be "i word 9", so after detecting the i to insert I have to read a string and an int.
Anyone has any idea how to do this? I am sorry is this seems simple, but I am new to programming.

edit: Here is what I have so far

```
while (loop) {
        fscanf(stdin,"%c",&par);
        if (strcmp(&par,"i")){
            scanf("%s %d",palavra,p);
            raiz = insere(raiz,&palavra,p);
        }
        else if (strcmp(&par,"b")){
            scanf("%s",palavra);
            busca(raiz,&palavra);
        }
        else if (strcmp(&par,"q"))
                 loop = 0;
    }
```

edit 2: This is what I have now, I am having problems reading the string and integer when the parameter is i, somehow it crashes the function

```
while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == 'f')
            break;
        else if (c == 'i'){
            fscanf(stdin,"%s",&palavra);
            scanf("%d",&p);
            raiz = insere(raiz,palavra,p);
        }
        else if (c == 'b') {
            scanf("%s",palavra);
            busca(raiz,palavra);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kind'a sounds like a while (true) loop.  Perhaps you could show us what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to programming! The best way to approach a problem like this is one step at a time, trying a little bit at a time and adding on to it. Write some code to read the chars. Then test it. Then write some code to figure out which parameter has been named. Then test that. Then write some code to try making a loop around it. Then test that. And so on. You may come to a point where you really have no idea where to go next, but then at least you'll have come far enough that we can help you with a suggestion :-)

Comment: For this, forget strings. Use `getchar` to read a char, and compare it to other chars, so you don't need to use C string functions.

Comment: ...and if you do use C string functions, read the docs. For example with `strcmp`, you are using the return value wrong now.

Comment: ...hmm, ok, to clarify, for the stuff you describe in text, you do need strings. But for the stuff in code snippet, not.

Comment: So, to read the parameters getchar is really the thing, but after that I am getting errors while passing the string and number to the function when trying to insert :(

Answer (score 0):

The code you have doesn't look too bad compared to what I believe you want.  You can replace the "while (loop)" with "while (1)" and then your exist code "loop = 0;" with "break;" which is a bit more standard way of doing things.  Also "fscanf(stdin..." is the same as "scanf(..." ... scanf will read from stdin by default.  You might want to check the docs for strcmp because it returns 0 for an exact match and I don't think that will do what you want in your 'if' statements.  You should be able to use scanf to read in the values you want, is it giving you an error?

Answer (score 0):

You are using 3 separated scans. That means you can't input this "i word 9", but input one command or parameter at the time separated by EOL(pressing enter).. i, enter, word, enter, 9, enter ... Then the function should actually get further in those "if"s. With those scans you also should consider printing information about expected inputs ("Choose action q/i/f")
And I would recommend using something to test those inputs.

```
if (scanf("%d", &p) == 0) {
   printf("Wrong input");
   break;
}
```